# Pandas changes default numpy array format

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there any way to prevent `pandas` from changing the default print format for `numpy` arrays?

With plain `numpy`, I get:

```
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([  1.23450000e+02,   6.00000000e-02])
```

After I import `pandas`, I get:

```
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([ 123.45,    0.06])
```

Can I stop it from doing this as a configuration setting? I don't want to have to wrap every "import pandas" with a "foo=np.get_printoptions(); import pandas; np.set_printoptions(**foo)", but that's the best I can come up with.

As it is, if I import pandas in one place, I get doctest errors from another.

Answer (score 2):

You should only have to wrap the first import pandas with np.set_printoptions(foo) since python will cache it. See below:

```
import numpy
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([  1.23450000e+02,   6.00000000e-02])
>>> import pandas
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([ 123.45,    0.06])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(edgeitems=3,infstr='inf', linewidth=75, nanstr='nan', precision=8, suppress=False, threshold=1000)
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([  1.23450000e+02,   6.00000000e-02])
>>> import pandas
>>> numpy.array([123.45, 0.06])
array([  1.23450000e+02,   6.00000000e-02])
```

Comment: Thanks, but we're using nose to load in the tests, which means I don't know in what order the modules will be loaded. I could always put it in the top package-level __init__, but that feels invasive. Plus, I'd have to change everyone else's doctests. I can't help but think that pandas shouldn't be changing numpy package-level globals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit irritating as I think that NumPy should have `suppress=True` as its default. I'm changing pandas to not change it.

Comment: Thanks, Wes! That would be great. If I run into you at DataGotham, I'll say thanks in person.